# In SharePoint Online, hub site permissions not synced to associated hub sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

Parent hub site:  ER

Child hub site: HR (associated with ER hub site)

"Sync hub permissions to associated sites" - turned on

ER@x.com hub visitor added to parent hub site

Result:

ER@x.com added to folder Hub Visitors under Permissions for ER hub site.

ER@x.com not visible in folder Hub Visitors under Permission for HR hub site.

Accessing HR site as ER@x.com visitor resulted in access denied.

If hub visitor permissions are synced with associated sites, why am I getting an access denied error?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, this is caused by the wrong order of operations.

1.First, you should register the ER as hub site.

2.Then, go to Site permissions of ER -> Turn on Sync hub permissions to associated sites.

3.Add Hub Visitors.

4.Associate the HR site with ER hub site.